# Write a query to check that all the routes in the circuit called "Beginner" are compatible

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Slot(sid, wall, x, y)
Hold(hid, color, desc)
Route(rid, name, circuit)
Placement(rid, hid, sid)
```

Slot represents the possible locations for a hold.  sid is a surrogate key, the wall is the name of the wall (e.g., "north," "front"), `(x,y)` is the location on the wall, measured in meters.

Hold manages the inventory of shaped resin pieces that simulate outcroppings on which to step or grab.

`Route` is a set of holds attached to particular slots.  `name` is a descriptive text string.  `circuit` is a label indicating that this route is part of a set of related routes.
`sid, hid, rid` are integers.

**Question**: A conflict is when two holds occupy the same slot.  A set of routes are compatible if they have no conflicts.  Write a query to check that all the routes in the circuit called `Beginner` are compatible.  Your query should return the sid that is causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There would be two sids that conflict with each other as I understand it, but the question only requires one. If their Ids are numeric and incremental then this query should return the latest one.

```
SELECT MAX(sid)
FROM placement JOIN Route ON Route.rid = Placement.rid
WHERE Route.circuit = 'Beginner'
GROUP BY hid HAVING Count(sid) > 1
```

Comment: why do you have to count sid?

Comment: You are counting the number of records in Placement that have the same values for rid for the beginner circuit.